# Can I safely include bootstrap.js in bootstrap-vue project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am developing a small VueJS app, similar to a calculator, that will be mounted to a DOM element within an existing "static" page on a Bootstrap 4 themed CMS. The nav bar and other site functionality all relies on vanilla Bootstrap 4 CSS/JS. There will not be any DOM interaction between the non-Vue and Vue portions of the page. The non-Vue portions are simple content and navigation.

Currently, without using Bootstrap-Vue, everything is working fine.

I would like to use Bootstrap-Vue components within the VueJS managed portions of the page. According to those components' docs:

> If you've already been using Bootstrap 4, there are a couple adjustments you may need to make to your project: [1] Remove the bootstrap.js file from your page scripts or build pipeline, [2]...

Since the non-Vue portions of the page use bootstrap.js, can I simply include both the bootstrap.js as well as the bootstrap-vue.js libraries at runtime? Any issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example i have used two part one is specified to Vue and another one for bootstrap only.

I'm providing the following simplified example to show you how to do that

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
    item:'',
     currentPassword:'',
     req:false
    }
  },
  methods: {
  changePassword: function() {
    this.req=true;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Add this after vue.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="outOfVue">
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div>
    
    <b-form validated="" id="passwordChangeForm" @submit.prevent="changePassword" class="container-fluid">
      <b-form-group id="currentPassword" label="Old password">
        <b-form-input id="password" v-model="currentPassword" placeholder="Enter your old Password" type="password" :required="req" />
      </b-form-group>
      <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
    </b-form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The example is very helpful. This is exactly what I needed. I can now piece together pages using the CMS backend and they will be able to work together.